# Memory usage in python

Tags: python, memory

For a small contest, I need to solve a problem with Python. However, the solution must not use more than **20MB of memory**.

I worked hard to come up with a good solution. When I submit it, it works fine with the first 4 examples but does not pass the 5th one. Reason: my script used more memory than allowed.

I have no idea how to better that, and generally how to see my memory usage in Python. So if you could give me **a way to calculate memory usage**, or any tips on what should be avoided to save memory, that would be nice!

PS: I'm working with Spyder 3.0.2. My script already uses a minimal amount of arrays and shrink them when possible.

Edit: Thanks your for all of your answers, here's my code if you have ideas

```
"""
Small description of the problem
You are a taxi
You need to satisfy request
A request is a person asking you to take him from pos1 to pos2
There are gas station on the map, you start at the first one
The goal is to satisfy every request while minimizing the amount of gas used BETWEEN two stations
This is a quite non-intuitive problem, we dont care about the total amount of gas
We care about the gas used between two stations
In this problem, the gas used is the distance squared

Example: 2 stations, one request
Stations  [0,0] , [2,2]
Request   [3,3] =>[2,1]
Solution: You start at [0,0]
 [0,0] => [2,2] => [3,3] => [2,2] => [2,1] => [2,2] => [0,0]
Station=>Station=> start =>Station=>  end  =>Station=>Station
D:   sqrt(8)  sqrt(2)  sqrt(2)    1        1      sqrt(8)
gas:   8       (2*sqrt(2))**2      (2*1)**2         8
"""

def D( pos1, pos2 ):
    # Returns the distance between two positions pos[x,y]
    return (( pos1[0]-pos2[0] )**2 + ( pos1[1]-pos2[1] )**2 )**0.5

def SPP( pos, stations ):
    # Returns the closest station to a certain point
    indice = 0
    mini = D( pos, stations[0] )
    for i in range(1,  len(stations) ):
        if D( pos, stations[i] ) < mini:
            mini = D( pos, stations[i] )
            indice = i
    return indice

def SAcc( w, maxi, stations ):
    # Returns the list of accessible stations given a specific way
    last = w[-1]
    liste = [x for x in range(len(stations)) if x not in w] # Pas visitées
    listem= []
    for i in range(len(liste)):
        if D( stations[last] , stations[liste[i]]) < maxi:  # Si proche
            listem.append( liste[i] )
    return listem

def Dmaxw( w, stations ):
    # Returns the maximum distance between two stations of a given way
    return max([ D( stations[w[i-1]], stations[w[i]] ) for i in range(1,len(w)) ])

def OptiDeplS( a, b, stations ):
    # Optimize the movement from a station a to a station b, returns the minimal distance of the optimized way
    optw = [a,b]
    ways = [[a]]
    maxi = D( stations[a], stations[b])
    while ways != []:
        nways = []
        for w in ways:
            for i in SAcc( w, maxi, stations):
                nways.append( w + [i] )
        ways = []
        for w in nways:
            if w[-1] == b:
                if Dmaxw( w, stations ) < maxi:
                    maxi = Dmaxw( w, stations )
                    optw = w
            elif Dmaxw( w, stations ) < maxi:
                ways.append( w )
    return Dmaxw( optw, stations )

def main(n, m, stations, request):
    Dmax = 0
    SPPr = [ [SPP(r[0],stations),SPP(r[1],stations)] for r in request ]
    pos = 0
    for i in range(m):
        Dmax = max( Dmax, OptiDeplS( pos, SPPr[i][0], stations ))
        Dmax = max( Dmax, 2*D(stations[SPPr[i][0]], requetes[i][0]) )
        Dmax = max( Dmax, OptiDeplS( SPPr[i][0], SPPr[i][1], stations ))
        Dmax = max( Dmax, 2*D(stations[SPPr[i][1]], requetes[i][1]) )
        pos = SPPr[i][1]
    Dmax = max( Dmax, OptiDeplS( SPPr[-1][0], pos, stations ))
    return round(Dmax**2)

n = 9 # nb of stations
m = 5 # nb of request
stations = [ [1,7],[7,6],[4,1],[2,2],[1,0],[0,3],[2,4],[9,1],[5,5] ]
request = [ [[4,8],[9,7]],[[8,8],[1,6]],[[9,5],[1,4]],[[0,0],[3,5]],[[6,4],[10,0]] ]
print( main(n, m, stations, request) )
```

Comment: This is very vague. If you post the script people may be able to tell you which parts are memory-inefficient.

Comment: `psutil` module can provide all the information on processes, including the current one.

Comment: Is Python the only language allowed in the contest or are things like C allowed?

Comment: Hi, C is allowed however I'm not used to it and for this problem, the adaptation would be fastidious. I'm using non-fixed size arrays all the time, C is too structured for me :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're on windows, you can see memory usage of the python process

```
def memory():
    import os
    from wmi import WMI
    w = WMI('.')
    result = w.query("SELECT WorkingSet FROM Win32_PerfRawData_PerfProc_Process WHERE IDProcess=%d" % os.getpid())
    return int(result[0].WorkingSet)
```

If you provide your script someone could tell you where memory usage can be improved.

Comment: what if he uses *nix?

Comment: I added the script :)